# Is there any way to effectively annotate a conditional statement?

Tags: java, annotations, aop

I would like to be able to selectively print on conditional statements with as little code as possible. For instance, if I wanted to debug a code path, I would do something like this:

```
if(x>3) @ifTrue("condition A") {
    doStuff();
} else if (x < 0) @ifFalse("condition B") {
    doOtherStuff();
} else {
    doLastStuff();
}
```

And a class somewhere else that defines what the annotations do. I know this isn't possible in vanilla java, but I was thinking some sort of AOP setup would facilitate it.

Comment: IMO the current code without any annotation nor AOP is the best bet for your case. Note that adding AOP for this case is way overkill, you may *gain* less code but you use more resources to accomplish this.

Comment: why not simply `if (x > 3) { someOtherClass.conditionA(); doStuff(); } else if { ... } `?